# Python list created but unable to find the value when searched

Tags: python, list

Hi I am new to python (3rd day of learning to code anything). I am having trouble with my program. See below. After I create an account for the user I am trying to find the account but whenever I choose choice 2, (def get_account_info(self):) and copy and paste the account just created, the result is account not found. I know the account exist because I just created it. What can I do to make it work?

I tried making it into a loop thinking maybe it just needed to go around again and missed it the first time. That did not work. I am really new so if this was a dumb idea please don't make fun lol.

`

```
class BankManager:
    account = []  
    def __init__(self):
        self.bank = Bank()
        self.account = []
        
    def main(self):
        while True:
            print("What do you want to do?")
            print("1. Open an account")
            print("2. Get account information and balance")
            print("3. Change PIN")
            print("4. Deposit money in account")
            print("5. Transfer money between accounts")
            print("6. Withdraw money from account")
            print("7. ATM withdrawal")
            print("8. Deposit change")
            print("9. Close an account")
            print("10. Add monthly interest to all accounts")
            print("11. End Program")
            
            choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
            if choice == "1":
                self.open_account()
            elif choice == "2":
                self.get_account_info()
            elif choice == "3":
                self.change_pin()
            elif choice == "4":
                self.deposit_money()
            elif choice == "5":
                self.transfer_money()
            elif choice == "6":
                self.withdraw_money()
            elif choice == "7":
                self.atm_withdrawal()
            elif choice == "8":
                self.deposit_change()
            elif choice == "9":
                self.close_account()
            elif choice == "10":
                bank.add_monthly_interest()
            elif choice == "11":
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")
    
    def prompt_for_account_number_and_pin(self, bank):
        account_number = input("Enter account number: ")
        account = bank.get_account_by_number(account_number)
        if account is None:
            print(f"Account not found for account number: {account_number}")
            return None
        pin = input("Enter PIN: ")
        if account.pin != pin:
            print("Invalid PIN")
            return None
        return account
    
    def open_account(self):
        # Prompt user for account owner's information
        firstName = BankUtility.promptUserForString("Enter Account Owner's First Name:" )
        lastName = BankUtility.promptUserForString("Enter Account Owner's Last Name:" )
        ssn = BankUtility.promptUserForString("Enter Account Owner's SSN (9 digits):" )   
        # Generate a unique account number
        accountNumber = random.randint(10000000, 99999999)
        while self.bank.get_account_by_number(accountNumber) is not None:
            accountNumber = random.randint(10000000, 99999999)
    # Create a new Account object and set its fields
        account = Account(owner_first_name=firstName, owner_last_name=lastName, ssn=ssn)
        account.set_account_number(accountNumber)
        account.set_owner_first_name(firstName)
        account.set_owner_last_name(lastName)
        account.set_ssn(ssn)
        account.set_pin(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    # Add the new account to the Bank
        if self.bank.addAccountToBank(account):
            self.account.append(account)
            print("Account created successfully:")
            print(account.to_string())
            #print(self.account)
            for i in range(0, len(self.account)):    
                print(self.account[i]),                  
        else:
            print("No more accounts available.")
    # Return to main menu
       
        
    def change_pin(self):
        account = self.prompt_for_account_number_and_pin(self.bank)
        if account:
            new_pin = input("Enter a new 4-digit PIN: ")
            if re.match("^[0-9]{4}$", new_pin):
                account.set_pin(new_pin)
                print("PIN changed successfully")
            else:
                print("Invalid PIN format. PIN must be a 4-digit number.")
    
    def deposit_money(self):
        account = self.prompt_for_account_number_and_pin(self.bank)
        if account:
            # Prompt for an amount to deposit and update the account in the bank
            pass
    
    def transfer_money(self):
        source_account = self.prompt_for_account_number_and_pin(self.bank)
        if source_account:
            # Prompt for a destination account number and amount to transfer
            # Update both accounts in the bank
            pass
    
    def withdraw_money(self):
        account = self.prompt_for_account_number_and_pin(self.bank)
        if account:
            # Prompt for an amount to withdraw and update the account in the bank
            pass
    
    def atm_withdrawal(self):
        account = self.prompt_for_account_number_and_pin(self.bank)
        if account:
            # Prompt for an amount to withdraw (in multiples of 20) and update the account in the bank
            pass
    
    def deposit_change(self):
        account = self.prompt_for_account_number_and_pin(self.bank)
        if account:
            # Prompt for an amount of change to deposit and update the account in the bank
            pass
    
    def get_account_info(self):
        account_number = input("Enter account number: ")
        account_found = False
        for account in self.account:
            if account.get_account_number() == account_number:
                print(account.to_string())
                account_found = True
                break
        if not account_found:
                print(f"Account {account_number} not found.")
            
      
           
  
    
#importing random to generate random values
import random
#importing regular expression support
import re

class Account:
    def __init__(self, owner_first_name, owner_last_name, ssn):
        self.__account_number = random.randint(10000000, 99999999) # 8-digit integer that cannot start with 0
        self.__owner_first_name = owner_first_name
        self.__owner_last_name = owner_last_name
        self.__ssn = ssn
        self.__pin = str(random.randint(0, 9999)).zfill(4) # 4-digit PIN 
        self.__balance = 0
    
    def to_string(self):
        return f"""
        Account Number {self.__account_number}
        First Name { self.__owner_first_name}
        Last Name {self.__owner_last_name} 
        Pin {self.__pin}
        Balance:  {self.__balance}"""
    
    
    # getters and setters for each attribute
    def get_account_number(self):
        return self.__account_number
    
    def set_account_number(self, account_number):
        self.__account_number = account_number

    def get_owner_first_name(self):
        return self.__owner_first_name

    def set_owner_first_name(self, owner_first_name):
        self.__owner_first_name = owner_first_name

    def get_owner_last_name(self):
        return self.__owner_last_name

    def set_owner_last_name(self, owner_last_name):
        self.__owner_last_name = owner_last_name

    def get_ssn(self):
        return self.__ssn

    def set_ssn(self, ssn):
        self.__ssn = ssn

    def get_pin(self):
        return self.__pin

    def set_pin(self, pin):
        self.__pin = pin

    def get_balance(self):
        return self.__balance

    def set_balance(self, balance):
        self.__balance = balance

    # deposit method that adds the amount to the account balance and returns the new balance
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.__balance += amount
        return self.__balance

    # withdraw method that subtracts the amount from the account balance and returns the new balance
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.__balance -= amount
        return self.__balance

    # isValidPIN method that compares the given PIN to the account's PIN and returns True if they match
    def is_valid_pin(self, pin):
        return self.__pin == pin

    # toString method that returns a string representation of the account's attributes
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Account Number: {self.__account_number}\nOwner First Name: {self.__owner_first_name}\nOwner Last Name: {self.__owner_last_name}\nSSN: {self.__ssn}\nPIN: {self.__pin}\nBalance: {self.__balance}"

    def set_account_number(self, account_number):
        self.__account_number = account_number
    
  


class BankUtility:
    
    @staticmethod
    def isNumeric(s):
        return bool(re.match('^[0-9]+$', s))
    
    @staticmethod
    def promptUserForString(prompt):
        return input(prompt)
    
    @staticmethod
    def promptUserForPositiveNumber(prompt):
        while True:
            num = input(prompt)
            if BankUtility.isNumeric(num):
                num = float(num)
                if num <= 0:
                    print("Amount cannot be negative. Try again.")
                else:
                    return num
            else:
                print("Invalid input. Try again.")
    
    @staticmethod
    def convertFromDollarsToCents(amount):
        return int(amount * 100)
    
    @staticmethod
    def generateRandomInteger(min_val, max_val):
        return random.randint(min_val, max_val)
    
class Bank:
    MAX_ACCOUNTS = 100

    def __init__(self):
        self.account = [None] * Bank.MAX_ACCOUNTS

    def get_account_by_number(self, account_number):
        for account in self.account:
            if account is not None and account.get_account_number == account_number:
                return account
        return None

    def addAccountToBank(self, account):
        for i in range(Bank.MAX_ACCOUNTS):
            if self.account[i] is None:
                self.account[i] = account
                return True
        print("No more accounts available")
        return False

    def removeAccountFromBank(self, account):
        for i in range(Bank.MAX_ACCOUNTS):
            if self.account[i] is not None and self.account[i].getAccountNumber() == account.getAccountNumber():
                self.account[i] = None
                return True
        return False

    def findAccount(self, accountNumber):
        for account in self.account:
            if account is not None and account.getAccountNumber() == accountNumber:
                return account
        return None
    
    def add_account(self, name, balance):
        self.account.append(Account)
        self.account[name] = balance

    def addMonthlyInterest(self, annualInterestRate):
        monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0 / 100.0
        for i in range(Bank.MAX_ACCOUNTS):
            if self.account[i] is not None:
                balance = self.account[i].getBalance()
                monthlyInterest = balance * monthlyInterestRate
                self.account[i].deposit(monthlyInterest)


bank_manager = BankManager()
bank=Bank()
bank.add_account
bank_manager.main()`
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and particularly the Minimal part of [mre]

Comment: Without reading the massive wall of code, it seems like you missed a `()` after `bank.add_account`. What this does is it calls the `add_account` method of the `bank` object.

Comment: The string `'123'` does not equal the integer `123`. You store the account number as an integer, but input from the user is a string.